# Powershell script to download Salesforce backup

Tags: powershell, salesforce

Would it be possible to use Powershell to create a script that can retrieve and download the salesforce backup (Created via Salesforce schedule). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can access Salesforce via APIs, SOAP or REST:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

Related question:  [How to automate download of weekly export service files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178279/how-to-automate-download-of-weekly-export-service-files)